# How can I check if aws queue exists using ansible?

Tags: ansible

How can I create an aws sqs queue using ansible playbook if does not alreay exist?

I do not know how to check using ansible

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/sqs_queue_module.html try starting here

Comment: This is a common miss-conception for ansible beginners who did not yet get the concept of [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). You don't check if it exists and create if it doesn't. You describe the state: "the queue must exists". Then the ansible module will make sure it does and take appropriate action: create it or report it's already there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking for sqs_queue (let's say), the following code snippet might help

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: create queue if needed
      sqs_queue:
        name: "test_queue"
        state: "present"
        region: "us-east-1"
```

The task would create a queue if not already exists. You should see `changed` in the output.

If it exists then it will report `ok` meaning the current state already matches the required state.

You can get more information in [official docs sqs queue ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/sqs_queue_module.html)

Comment: Agreed and changed Mr @Zeitounator, thank you. That's a good code review right there :)

Comment: @codeaprendiz I also thought about it exactly like your first answer :D.